# Rails: Storing BigDecimal in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, decimal, bigdecimal

I am handling a bunch of BigDecimals, which I want to store to my database. Ideally without any loss of accuracy. I don't know the nicest way to achieve that.

---

*This came to my mind:*

```
t.decimal :value, precision: 1000, scale: 30
```

It does not look like a good way to approach this problem. 1. it still compromises accuracy. 2. It's is getting unnecessarily large.

---

Is there a way to store the object, e.g.: `#<BigDecimal:586a238,'0.563E0',9(36)>` to the database (within a `text` column) and then re-initialize it as a BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [`composed_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html).

But I prefer using custom getter and setter methods because I thing they are easier to read and to understand.

Example: Imagine your attribute is named `foo` and you want to use `BigDecimal` in the app but store the value as a string in the database:

```
def foo
  BigDecimal.new(read_attribute(:foo))
end

def foo=(foo)
  write_attribute(:foo, foo.to_s)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By default a PostgreSQL Decimal has a range of "up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point". Is that not enough?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html

Just use:

```
t.decimal :value
```

Comment: I previously used this solution, but that led to some calculation errors. Tackling it like proposed by spickermann, everything works fine. :)

Comment: This is very strange. I would urge you to raise an issue on this. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues